# Filtrar códigos elementos

Tags: javascript, regex, vue.js

Fala, galera.. Blz? To com uma dúvida aqui. Estou desenvolvendo um app de chat em vue, e digamos que eu envie ou receba uma mensagem da seguinte forma:

`msg = "Oi, fulano. Acesse esse <a href="link">link</a> e digite <span>Meu nome é <a href="teste">teste</a></span>. Depois disso, vá até tal lugar e então cole o código <header> <div class="title text-center"><h1>Testando</h1></div> </header>."`

Ao renderizar a mensagem, será criado o link, span, h1, etc.. Existe alguma forma de , por exemplo, eu 'varrer' a mensagem toda e verificar todas as tags, elementos, scripts, enfim , e o que começar diferente de e terminar com eu adicionar a tag code na frente e no final? Ai, no caso, a seguinte mensagem ficaria assim:

Oi, fulano. Acesse esse link e digite `<code><span>Meu nome é <a href="teste">teste</a></span><code>`. Depois disso, vá até tal lugar e então cole o código `<code><header> <div class="title text-center"><h1>Testando</h1></div> </header></code>.`

Ou seja, ele verificou que existe um link e não fez nada, depois verificou que existe uma tag span, encontrou tudo que está dentro dela e adicionou ela dentro de uma tag code.. continuou, viu que existe uma tag header, encontrou o final dela e adicionou ela dentro de uma tag code. Tentei com regex e não consegui nem na bala.. Se alguém puder me dar um help.. <3

Comment: Não percebi bem a pergunta, podes rever e explicar melhor o código/string de entrada e como queres o resultado? o `<a>` não deve ficar `<code><a></code>`?

Comment: Isso, Sérgio! Links (a) nao devem ficar dentro de code. PORÉM, caso esse link esteja dentro de qualquer outra tag, ai ele é englobado junto com a code!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sugiro não fazeres esse trabalho com regex mas sim criando elementos com a API JavaScript.

Não está claro na pergunta como vais usar/integrar isso no Vue, mas podes fazer algo assim:

```js
const msg = `Oi, fulano. Acesse esse <a href="link">link</a> e digite <span>Meu nome é <a href="teste">teste</a></span>. Depois disso, vá até tal lugar e então cole o código <header> <div class="title text-center"><h1>Testando</h1></div> </header>.`

function wrapInCode(el) {
  const parent = el.parentElement;
  const code = document.createElement('code');
  parent.replaceChild(code, el);
  code.appendChild(el);
}

const proxy = document.createElement('div');
proxy.innerHTML = msg;
[...proxy.children].forEach(el => {
  if (el.tagName.toLowerCase() !== 'a') wrapInCode(el);
});

console.log(proxy.innerHTML);
```

Comment: Quase consegui aqui com regex mesmo. 
Exemplo do regex https://regex101.com/r/yGqic2/1 
Ele está fazendo quase como quero. Ignorando os links que estão fora de outras tags do html e selecionando tudo que seja diferente de text e link.
Porém, ao dar um match no regex, ele me retorna certinho `<span>Meu nome é <a href=\"teste\">teste</a></span>` , mas na outra ele retorna quebrado.
Veja, por favor, se puder, o exemplo no jsbin 
https://jsbin.com/rokivuvuyo/edit?js,console,output

Comment: @RafaelPelizza fazer com regex é muito menos seguro que como indiquei. A minha resposta é sem regex, porque acho que é a melhor solução. Não tenho tempo de ajudar a procurar uma solução com regex que já sei que pode ter casos inesperados e vai precisar de ajustes sem fim.

Comment: Certo. Vou ver c consigo aqui sim!

Answer (score 0):

Pelo o que entendi, você quer imprimir como HTML somente a tag `code`, sendo que o seu conteúdo deve ser mostrado como texto simples. O que pode ser feito é aplicar um regex para selecionar o texto que deve ficar dentro das tags code, envolver esse texto com as tags `code` e depois substituir o conteúdo da mensagem. Porém, apenas isso não é o suficiente, porque quando você for imprimir a mensagem, as outras tags que estão dentro de `code` vão ser impressas como HTML, ou seja, um `h1` vai ser impresso como um texto bem grande na mensagem. Para contornar esse problema, "convertemos" o HTML dentro das tags `code` para texto simples. A solução final, com Javascript puro, fica assim:

```js
// Esse é o regex que para selecionar somente o conteúdo entre as tags <span> e <header>, você pode adicionar outras tags conforme necessário
var regex = /<(span|header)(.*?)<\/(span|header)>/gm;

// Mensagem que vamos usar para testar
var msg = "Oi, fulano. Acesse esse <a href='link'>link</a> e digite <span>Meu nome é <a href='teste'>teste</a></span>. Depois disso, vá até tal lugar e então cole o código <header> <div class='title text-center'><h1>Testando</h1></div> </header>.";

// Aplicando o regex na mensagem
var resultado = msg.match(regex);

// Para cada resultado do regex, que é um array, envolvemos o texto com a tag <code> e substituímos o texto antigo com o novo
resultado.forEach(function(valor, index) {
  msg = msg.replace(valor, "<code>" + valor + "</code>")
});

// Porém, o que está dentro da tag <code> vai continuar sendo impresso como html, por exemplo, o texto com a tag <h1> vai sair bem grande. Para corrigir isso vamos substituir todo o conteúdo HTML dentro das tags <code> para texto simples, dessa forma:
document.getElementById("resultado").innerHTML = msg;
document.querySelectorAll("code").forEach(function(valor, index) {
  valor.textContent = valor.innerHTML;
});
```

```html
<div id="resultado">

</div>
```

Comment: Qual isso amigo hehe
Os links (a) nao devem ficar dentro de code. PORÉM, caso esse link esteja dentro de qualquer outra tag, ai ele é englobado junto com a code!

Comment: Quase consegui aqui com regex mesmo. 
Exemplo do regex https://regex101.com/r/yGqic2/1 
Ele está fazendo quase como quero. Ignorando os links que estão fora de outras tags do html e selecionando tudo que seja diferente de text e link.
Porém, ao dar um match no regex, ele me retorna certinho `<span>Meu nome é <a href=\"teste\">teste</a></span>` , mas na outra ele retorna quebrado.
Veja, por favor, se puder, o exemplo no jsbin 
https://jsbin.com/rokivuvuyo/edit?js,console,output